# apt-get install: Error: Timeout was reached?

Tags: debian, apt-get, dpkg

What has gone wrong if this error message appears **AFTER** `apt-get` has finished downloading and installing packages?

```
...  
Processing triggers for menu ...  
Error: Timeout was reached
```

This was on a Debian Wheezy/Sid.

Comment: give more information (distribution, the command line used, mirror list ...), maybe it will guide someone to help you

Comment: What package are you updating or installing?

Comment: terdon: Frankly, I don't even remember what I've installed (I think it was gdb). This question could probably be deleted, since it doesn't provide a lot of information for debugging. Thanks for the heads-up, I'll look through my older questions.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as you:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install intel-microcode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-686-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 426 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ sid/non-free intel-microcode i386 1.20130222.5 [426 kB]
Fetched 426 kB in 11s (36.8 kB/s)                                                                              
(Reading database ... 283637 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace intel-microcode 1.20130222.5 (using .../intel-microcode_1.20130222.5_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement intel-microcode ...
Setting up intel-microcode (1.20130222.5) ...
Updating microcode on all online processors...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.9-1-686-pae
Error: Timeout was reached
$
```

Then was thinking that `initramfs` has something to do with it, with a hint that I got from the `dpkg.log` file.

```
2013-07-13 13:54:57 startup archives unpack
2013-07-13 13:55:09 upgrade intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:09 status half-configured intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:09 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:09 status half-installed intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:10 status half-installed intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:10 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:10 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:11 startup packages configure
2013-07-13 13:55:11 configure intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5 
2013-07-13 13:55:11 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:11 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:11 status unpacked intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:12 status half-configured intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:12 status installed intel-microcode:i386 1.20130222.5
2013-07-13 13:55:12 status triggers-pending initramfs-tools:all 0.113
2013-07-13 13:55:12 trigproc initramfs-tools:all 0.113 
2013-07-13 13:55:12 status half-configured initramfs-tools:all 0.113
2013-07-13 13:55:44 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.113
```

Hence I proceed to reinstall the `initramfs-tools` package using `apt-get --reinstall install initramfs-tools` and now the message got silent.

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install intel-microcode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-686-pae
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/426 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 283637 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace intel-microcode 1.20130222.5 (using .../intel-microcode_1.20130222.5_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement intel-microcode ...
Setting up intel-microcode (1.20130222.5) ...
Updating microcode on all online processors...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.9-1-686-pae
$
```

I don't know the exact reasons for it (nor how to reproduce it) and google don't help in that matters, but I left here a possible solution. But if I had to do a wild guess, maybe the timeout was due the triggers that *timed out* since for both, it happened after some triggers were used (`menu` in the case of OP, `update-initramfs` in mine).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu. Looked at the following solution:

https://fanf42.blogspot.com/2014/08/upgrading-to-ubuntu-1404-error-timeout.html

```
sudo /usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd --verbose
```

command showed me this error:

> Unit polkit.service not found

After reinstalling `policykit-1` package (`sudo apt reinstall policykit-1`) error has gone away.

Answer (score -1):

Running the following commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```